# Python Change Variables without Changing Parameters

Tags: python, variables, parameters

Is there a way to change the variables z, a, b, c, and d without modifying the parameters of func1? The reason is that I'm trying to iterate from values 0 to 100 for z, a, b, c, and d to find an optimal / best solution to a problem I'm working on. However, normally, z, a, b, c, and d are constants.

```
def func1(x, y):
    if x > z:
        return 0
    if (x + y) > 0:
        return func2(x, y, a, c)
    return func2(x, y, b, d)
```

Comment: Global variables are rarely a good idea, but for a quick test like this where they would be removed immediately afterwards, I don't think they would hurt...

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I forgot they existed -- I had them in Java but didn't expect them in Python as well.